# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS crashes often

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, emacs

I have a brand new thinkpad (x250) with Memory: 7,9 GiB - Processor: Intel Core i5-5200 CPU 2.20GHz x 4 - Graphics Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Boardwell GT2) x86/MMX/SSE2 - Disk 243,8 GB.

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on it (32-bit) about 2 months ago, and it was fine.
Since last week it crashes often (it logs out automatically while i am working), mostly when i am working with the Emacs texteditor (writing in clojure). What could the cause be?

Answer (score 0):

On a *50 series ThinkPad (Intel Broadwell) you should install the newest available kernel (4.2 from Wily) and graphics stack (from Vivid):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

Refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

I also strongly suggest to reinstall with 64 bit.

Comment: Ok, i have done this + installed the Kernel 4.2 from Wily. Now the Logout happens in a concrete moment: i am working with emacs24, writing a GUI in the programming language clojure (using the seesaw library). I have made a combobox, and each time i open the menu of the combobox and click on one of the selecteble choices it crashes! (logs out)

Comment: I am running now the 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

**How to Install Emacs 24.4 in Ubuntu:**

I couldnt find the PPA repository that contains Emacs 24.4. Fortunately, it’s not hard to build it from the source tarball. I’ve done it successfully in 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

If have the old Emacs 24.3 installed, you may first remove it from Ubuntu Software Center so that you can install the new version over it.

Press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open terminal, or open it from the Unity Dash.

Open Terminal to run commands

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Install the required dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
```

Notice the 24 change from option below.

While the installing process, you’ll be asked to configure the Postfix.

Now download Emacs 24.4 from its official [FTP download page.](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/)

Extract the source and go into the result folder in terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads && tar -xf emacs-24.4.tar.* && cd emacs-24.4
```

7. Finally compile the package by running commands below **one by one**.

   ./configure

   make

   sudo make install

Once done, you should be able to launch Emacs by running emacs or emacs-24.4 in terminal and lock the shortcut to the Unity Launcher.

**Emacs22**
 Below is emacs22 that seems more stable to me.

Fist save all data needed and uninstall old pkg. This is for **emacs22**

```
sudo apt-get purge pkgname
```

The pkgname = old emacs installed.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
 sudo apt-get build-dep emacs
```

This will download all the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install emacs && sudo apt-get upgrade emacs
```

This will dowload emacs

Comment: Ok, i have done this + installed the Kernel 4.2 from Wily. Now the Logout happens in a concrete moment: i am working with emacs24, writing a GUI in the programming language clojure (using the seesaw library). I have made a combobox, and each time i open the menu of the combobox and click on one of the selecteble choices it crashes! (logs out)

Comment: I am running now the 64-bit

Comment: I have updated my answer for emacs24

Comment: When i want to get the dependencies with `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24` i get in the terminal: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for emacs24`

Comment: Ok, i now have installed the 24.4. Why would you think the Emacs 24.3. (which i had installed from the Software Center) could cause the system to do logouts? Actually the Logouts happened allways as i was working in emacs.

Comment: Ok, it has happened again, despite my newly installed emacs.24.4.

Answer (score -1):

I could also experience this problem before i had a raw install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But it had stopped when i had created a new user. It is now working perfectly on my pc (hope it would work on others too).

**How to ceate new user:**

1. Login to guest account
2. Then logout. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
3. Now it Goes full black screen, log in with administator user.
4. Create a new user. Open-up terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo adduser username 
   sudo adduser username sudo
   ```
5. Now log out and login using new user & Delete the old user you'd have probs.

Hope this had helped for you.

Comment: Why should i create a new user? How does it come that the problem has to do with my current user?

Comment: Because a broken user config may crash your Desktop Environment. So testing with a fresh user makes always sense.

Answer (score -1):

New account can be easily added via system settings>user accounts Also you have 8GB memory and your ideal Ubuntu version needs to be x64. I have Ubuntu on X240, X220 Thinkpads and they run fine. Make sure to install TLP PPA and install TLP and add Thinkpad Extra PPA and add the utilities as well.

Check dmesg for segfaults. Try out x64 version. Does the system crash while running a particular program?

Comment: What are the TLP PPA and Thinkpad Extra PPA? I am often using Emacs, so i have experienced this problem while doing stuff in Emacs, but i don't know if it has to do with it

Comment: http://www.linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html                         https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/thinkpad-extras

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury: TLP does help to save battery power but does not solve kernel/graphics bugs.

Comment: I am aware of that but I have three x250 at my univ and all are running good, two on LTS Ubuntu and one on Gentoo and thats why I am trying to diagnose whats causing your crashes. TLP is an added advisory.